# Check difference between 2 values of a same record type

Tags: ocaml, record

I have defined a record type with many labels. Quite often I need to check the difference between 2 values of this record type --- to see the contents of which labels are different.

I guess there is no automatic way to do that (e.g. iteration), I have to check different cases one by one.

For instance, to check if the 2 values have always same contents except one label, currently i do `{v0 with label1 = a_content_of_label1} = {v1 with label1 = a_content_of_label1}`, it does not look to me pretty, because I need to choose `a_content_of_label1` myself.

Is there a better way to do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: how would you do this in any other language?

Answer (score 6):

What about this:

```
v0 = {v1 with label1 = v0.label1}
```